# Capture json from file using ob_start in php

Tags: php, include, ob-start

I have a file that outputs JSON. I would like to capture this output in a second file. However, when I include the output file, nothing is getting captured and I'm wondering if ob_start does not work with JSON.

Output.php

The JSON output file outputs:

```
{"book":{"title":"Peter Pan","author":"JM Barrie"}}
```

The code that outputs it is:

```
echo json_encode(array('book'=>$book));
```

My code to capture this and print it from a second file is:

Bigpage.php

```
ob_start();
echo "got here"
include 'output.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output; //prints "got here". Does not print out anything from output.php
```

What am I doing wrong? Alternatively, how should can I capture and print this output?

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `;` after `echo "got here"`, idk if that's the case.
Im doing everything as you and the result is :

```
got here{"book":{"book":{"title":"Peter Pan","author":"JM Barrie"}}}
```

Is it what you expect?

Comment: Did you produce the output in the output.php file as echo json_encode(array('book'=>$book));  When I just echo out a string such as "Hello there" from the file I see it in the other file. However, If I echo out echo json_encode($someobject) it does not appear